# Is there a way to convert a NoneType into a String?

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert a NoneType that the user inputs into a string, in python?
This is my code:

```
topping = print(input("What topping would you like on your pizza?"))
requested_toppings = []
requested_toppings.append(topping)
print("Adding" + topping + "...")
print("\n Finished Making Your Pizza!")
```

I have tried using `str(topping)` between the requested toppings list and the append. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Print returns none. You should set topping to the output of the input function

Comment: Just remove `print`. If you need to display the value,  do it like this: `var = input('Enter text here:'); print(var)`. And construct a list from elements like this: `lst = [e]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to "convert" `None` to `str` -> `str(None)` which will result a string `'None'`. This is not what you want here.

You have a problem in your code - `input` returns a string, but you print it. `print` doesn't return a value, so after `topping = print(input("What topping would you like on your pizza?"))`, `topping` will be equal to `None`.

Instead, you should save the value from the `input` in the `topping` variable:

```py
topping = input("What topping would you like on your pizza?")
```

If no input is given, you will receive an empty string from the user, so you still won't need to convert `None` to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `print()` around the input function. The input function already prints the message as a prompt. The reason you are getting `None` is because the print function does not return anything, whereas the input function does.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
topping = input("What topping would you like on your pizza?")
requested_toppings = []
requested_toppings.append(topping)
print("Adding" + topping + "...")
print("\n Finished Making Your Pizza!")
```